# How can I delete "locally stored data" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

In Chrome, when I asked to see cookies, it shows me the following screen:

[image]

If I click the "Remove All" button, then the entries disappear, but if I re-open the dialog they appear again and apparently have not actually been deleted.

How can permanently delete this "cache storage"?

Comment: `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and **Time range : All time** is not solve your issue?

Comment: Try disconnecting from the internet and then delete them & check afterwards. Some cookies & stuff (usually from google or your default search?) gets downloaded (again) the second Chrome's online

Comment: @Arulkumar No, it does not remove the "Cache storage" entries.

Answer (score 3):

Not Sure will work or not, but you should try these anyway.

#### 1. `Clear Cookies` and `site data`

Follow the below [link](http://chrome://settings/siteData) in your browser and click  <kbd>Remove All</kbd>  .

```
chrome://settings/siteData
```

[image: All cookies and site data]

---

#### 2. `Clear Storage` in `Applications` tab in DevTools

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to Open Developer Tools.
- Head to Applications Tab
- Click on `Clear Storage` on the Left pane.
- Hit  <kbd>Clear Site Data</kbd>  at the bottom.

[image: Applications Storage]

---

#### 3. `Disable Cache` in `Settings` in DevTools.

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to Open Developer Tools.
- Hit  <kbd>F1</kbd>  OR Click on `More Options Icon` left to cross button Then click `Settings`
- Go to `Preferences` and Scroll down to **`Network`** Section.
- Check the checkbox [ ] Disable Cache (while DevTools is Open)

[image: Disable Cache]

---

#### 4. Reload Page Trick

- Hit  <kbd>F12</kbd>  OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to Open Developer Tools.
- Now, **`Right-Click`** on the `Page Reload/Refresh` button left to Home button. You will see 3 options.
- Click on 3rd one `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`
- You are good to go.

[image: Reload Page]

If anyone above doesn't helped you, feel free to add-in more here.

Comment: It looks to me that you have to go to the site that owns the local storage in order to remove it.  But if that site is no longer available, how do you clear that local storage?

Comment: @DanielWilliams link in first solution lets you filter saved domains and clear local storage of any of those (other way to access that screen is to search in settings for `permission`, then select `Site Settings` and `View permissions and data stored across sites` - tested in Chrome 74)